# wxPython: Copying text from RichTextCtrl

Tags: wxpython

I've been trying to figure out how to copy rich text from a RichTextCtrl to the clipboard. I'm able to copy the text just fine, but not the rich text information. For example, if I copy some bold text from my RichTextCtrl and then paste it in to another program, it is just plain text.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PyRTFParser](http://transana.org/developers/PyRTFParser/) project.

From the project website:

> ...the Cut, Copy, and Paste methods in the
>   RichTextCtrl support only plain text, not formatted
>   text
>
> Cut / Copy / Paste of RTF-formatted text through the
>   clipboard between Word on Windows and Word and
>   TextEdit on OS X has been implemented in the
>   PyRTFParserDemo.py file.